# Increment a number inside a div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to increase a number inside a  when an event happens. Eg. button click. On the first event the code works fine, but on following events the numbers 'double up' and I'm not sure why.

EG.
HTML:

```
  <div>
    <span class="userpointshead"> 130 </span>
    <button class="jquery-tester">Button</button>
  </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('.jquery-tester').click(function() {
  var points = parseInt($('.userpointshead').text());
  $('.userpointshead').text(points+5);
});
```

On the first button click, the contents of `.userpointshead` will be updated to `135`. On the second click they will be updated to `135140`. On the third click it updates to `135140135145` and so on.

I want it to go from 130 - 135 - 140 - 145 - etc.

I have also tried the following with the same results:

```
$('.jquery-tester').click(function() {
  var points = parseInt($('.userpointshead').text().trim(), 10);
  var newpoints = points + 5;
  $(".userpointshead").html(newpoints);
});
```

I feel I'm missing something very obvious but not sure what.

UPDATE: I have tried the same code with a new `<span>` and it works as I'd like. I still have know idea why the original won't work.. it's just a span with a number in.

Comment: your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/x6j7g0Lg/. Are you sure you're using parseInt in your original code too?

Comment: Yes I am sure, I just copied it over. I also see that the jsfiddle works fine, I'm a bit puzzled as to what is wrong now.

Comment: @RobHughes copy this to your code and see if it works with `event.preventDefault()` ... https://jsfiddle.net/x6j7g0Lg/1/

Comment: @caramba Just tried this but get the same outcome.

Comment: How about wrapping the function inside a `$(document).ready(function(){})`

Comment: @SouravDe Just tried this, same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have more or less solved it, although I do not understand or like the solution.

Adding an extra class to the `<span>` and executing the jquery on the new class let everything work as it should.

```
<span class="userpointshead user-points"> 130 </span>
<button class="jquery-tester">Button</button>


$('.jquery-tester').click(function() {
  var points = parseInt($('.user-points').text());
  $('.user-points').text(points+5);
});
```

I have no other jquery/javascript interfering with `.userpointshead` in my project and I can't understand why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I simply tried this and its working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.jquery-tester').click(function() {
  var points = parseInt($('.userpointshead').text());
  $('.userpointshead').text(points+5);
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <span class="userpointshead"> 130 </span>
    <button class="jquery-tester">Button</button>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your coude should work fine.
Maybe try this to check if the problem is not elsewhere:

```
$('.userpointshead').text(parseInt(points)+5);
```